# Using @Today in Marketing List Selection Criteria

Tags: acumatica

I'm using Acumatica 18.210.

On a GI, under Conditions, if I select a Data Field that is a date and check the "From Schema" checkbox, I get a date picker for Value1 that has @Today, @WeekStart, etc. on the right side of the date picker window.  My question is how can I get these same @(whatever) settings for the Selection Criteria on a dynamic Marketing List?  Is it possible?

I played around with extending and inheriting from the CRFixedFilterRow but, nothing useful yet.

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the values from the Condition dropdown instead of trying to set it in the Value1 and Value2

[image]